# Combine text files with the same header

Tags: text-processing, awk

With `csplit` I've been able to split a text file with a bunch of names and dates using these dates as a delimiter.

Examples of files:

File 'xx00':

```
1950
Frank
Church
James
McClure
```

File 'xx01':

```
1945
Zenon
```

File 'xx02':

```
1950
Bob
```

What I wish to do is merge all files with the same header (the year) with that year as the filename and without the header. So the output would be:

File '1950':

```
Frank 
Church
James
McClure
Bob
```

File '1945'

```
Zenon
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk` here:

```
awk 'FNR==1{ header=$0;next} {print >"file"header}' filexx*
```

Will produce one or more new files concatenating files with having same headers in first line:

```
$ cat file1945
Zenon
```

```
$ cat file1950
Frank
Church
James
McClure
Bob
```

**Explanations** with including quotes from [**`awk`** documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

The pre-defined built-in variable [**`FNR`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-FNR-variable-1) is the current record number in the current file. `awk` increments `FNR` each time it reads a new record (see [Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records)). `awk` resets `FNR` to zero each time it starts a new input file. So when we do `FNR==1` means we only take action and get that line when it's very first line of current file and save its contents into a variable called `header`.

The [**`next`** statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Next-Statement) forces `awk` to immediately stop processing the current record and go on to the next record. This means that no further rules are executed for the current record, and the rest of the current rule’s action isn’t executed, so the next time `FNR!=1` and this will cause to `awk` execute the next block which is [redirecting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) the `print` output (records/lines) into the file named `file####` (`####` will substitute with the value of `header` variable; remember you need to have quoted the part of the filename that it's a *string*.

We used [single-‘`>`’ redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) here. When this type of redirection is used, the *output-file* is erased before the first output is written to it. Subsequent writes to the same *output-file* do not erase *output-file*, but append to it. (This is different from how you use redirections in shell scripts.) If *output-file* does not exist, it is created.